# Regular expression: which pattern would return true if both exact words were found?

Tags: c#, regex

If my regex pattern `@"\b(word1|word2)\b"` returns true when only 1 of the exact words is found, which pattern would return true if both exact words were found?

The only examples I found were like I did it and return true whenever 1 word was found but I want it to return true when all words were found. So multiples of the same word don't count. I need to know if at least 1 occurrence of all words exists.

**Edit:**

Example:
"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"

pattern: `@"\b(fox|dog)\b"` <---- returns true

pattern: `@"\b(fox|elephant)\b"` <---- returns true, I want it to return false.

Add: I have to be flexible since the amount of words to search for depends on my users.

Comment: With word boundaries between them though? It would be really helpful if you'd give a sample word list and some sample strings which you want to match or not.

Comment: How about making 2 regexes? it would simplify a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using lookaheads

```
(?=.*\bWord1\b)(?=.*\bWord2\b).*
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2udtb)

`(?=.*\bWord1\b)` is a positive lookahead. It checks if the pattern inside occurs within the string. It does not match anything!

To match the string there is the `.*` at the end, but this will only be matched, if both lookaheads are true, i.e. both of your words are found within the string.

Answer (score 0):

the simple answer is to have two regex expressions one for the first word, and one for the other, if both return true (and them), then the result is true.

`@"\b(word1)\b"`   and  `@"\b(word2)\b"`

You can check [here](http://www.wellho.net/regex/java.html) also

Comment: He's using C# though, not Java.

Answer (score 0):

If you must,

```
@"\b(word1\b(.*\b)?word2|word2\b(.*\b)?word1)\b"
```

but it would be better to use two regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Stema's answer is the best imo.

The following is a simplified version of Charles

Given: "word and word2 and word3 and word4. word4 is a good guy, isn't he word1?"

(\bword4\b.*\bword2\b|\bword2\b.*\bword4\b)

BUT like i said Stema ftw